# How to globally format floats with comma as the decimal separator globally in Jinja2?

Tags: python, formatting, jinja2

I am creating very large document containing a lot of floating point numbers. The floating point formatting need to use comma's as the decimal separator. I could create a custom filter and manual transform each number but that seems cumbersome. How could I globally manipulate the jinja2 float formatting behaviour?